# Variaveis globais Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin-forms, visual-studio-2017, cross-platform

Existe a possibilidade de eu criar modulos para adicionar variáveis globais no Xamarin? como eu poderia criar variaveis que possam ser acessadas de qualquer lugar?

Comment: Putz eu tava fazendo errado, vlw mano abraços.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare uma classe estática dentro do módulo `App.xaml.cs` e declare os globais como sendo os seus campos.

## Exemplo:

```
public static class Globais
{
    public static string Aplicativo = "teste de globais";
    public static int Identificador = 33;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Agora como eu coloco esse tópico como resolvido? rsrs**

```
class ConfigSQL
{
    private static Int32 _index = 0;
    public static Int32 index
    {
        get { return _index; }
        set { _index = value; }
    }
 }
```